# Render XML Sitemap from Django View

Tags: xml, django, unicode, sitemap, utf

The following code in a Django view:

```
def sitemap(request):
    return render(request, 'sitemap.xml', content_type = 'text/xml')
```

yields the following error:

Exception Type: UnicodeDecodeError
Exception Value:
'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 0: invalid start byte

How can I resolve this? All I'm trying to do is to render an XML sitemap. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Not sure if this will help (I just learned about sitemaps today...), but maybe can get you going in the right direction: My quick search would suggest 0xff is a UTF-16 BOM. I am not entirely sure how you created your sitemap, but the first things I would do  would be to try and save the XML with UTF-8 encoding and then with or without BOM. I believe the [sitemap.xml standards](https://www.sitemaps.org/protocol.html) only support UTF-8 (doesn't mention anything about BOM).

Comment: I solved it. The sitemap XML document needed the following added to it:

Comment: @Foobar: please post your solution as a separate answer

Answer (score 1):

Django support built-in sitemap,here is a demo:

common/sitemaps.py

```
from django.contrib.sitemaps import Sitemap
from django.urls import reverse_lazy

from news.models import News


class StaticViewSitemap(Sitemap):
    priority = 0.5
    changefreq = 'weekly'

    def items(self):
        return ['index', 'news_index', 'version', 'rss']

    def location(self, item):
        return reverse_lazy(item)


class NewsSitemap(Sitemap):
    priority = 0.5
    changefreq = 'weekly'

    def items(self):
        return News.objects.all().order_by('-id')

    def location(self, item):
        return reverse_lazy('news_detail', kwargs={'pk': item.id})


sitemaps = {
    'static': StaticViewSitemap,
    'news': NewsSitemap,
}
```

your peoject main url.py:

```
from django.contrib.sitemaps.views import sitemap
from common.sitemaps import sitemaps

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', IndexView.as_view(), name='index'),
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^news/', include('news.urls')),
    url(r'^sitemap\.xml$', sitemap, {'sitemaps': sitemaps}, name='sitemap')
]
```

doc is [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/sitemaps/).

Comment: Okay, thanks. But what if I want to use an already created sitemap? I already have a sitemap.xml and simply want search engines to be able to spider it.